# Google Maps API v3 business version returns different address suggestions than the public one

Tags: google-maps-api-3, street-address

I am using Google Maps v3 (Javascript) for the product I am working on. When given an ambiguous address, like so:

```
  4701 Monte, Austin,,22153
```

the business api version, suggests the following 2 address:

```
  6000 Shepherd Mountain Cove, Austin, TX 78730, USA
  11010 Georgian Drive, Austin, TX 78753, USA
```

whereas the public api version,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4701+Monte,Austin,,22153,usa&sensor=false&v=3

suggests the following 3 addresses:

```
  4701 Mont Blanc Drive, Austin, TX 78738, USA
  6000 Shepherd Mountain Cove, Austin, TX 78730, USA
  11010 Georgian Drive, Austin, TX 78753, USA
```

Question is:

1. Why this difference between the 2 versions (business vs api)? Seems like the public version is more accurate?!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code which gets the result from the business API endpoint.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  What exactly would you like to see from an input address like that?  Certainly, it is ambiguous, or even flat wrong.  Within that ZIP Code, there is no delivery point that starts with a 4701.  Within Austin, there are a few that start with 4701.  I can see the 4701 Mont Blanc as a helpful suggestion but the 6000 Shepherd Mountain Cove and 11010 Georgian Drive?  With the Shepherd Mountain, the only thing it has in common with the input address is that it's in Austin and has "mont" in it.  The Georgian Drive address suggestion has only the city in common.

Comment: Actually the business API has the most accurate guess.from the link ie
`Iglesia Cristiana Monte Zion, 11010 Georgian Drive, Austin, TX 78753, USA`  and    
`Monte Vista Condominiums, 6000 Shepherd Mountain Cove, Austin, TX 78730, USA`
The third guess from the public API
`4701 Mont Blanc Drive, Austin, TX 78738, USA` only matches Austin

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason for the difference in results. Our code filters out anything that's not ROOFTOP or APPROXIMATIONS! The extra address was of the type RANGE_INTERPOLATIONS (basically not ROOFTOP OR APPROXIMATIONS)!